# Мега меню для WordPress без плагинов

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, виджет, location

проверка на содержание пунктами меню CSS-класса «has-mega-menu»
если да, то создаем новую область виджета для этого пункта меню

```
function  wpmm_init () {
    $location  =  ' mega_menu ' ;
    $css_class  =  ' has-mega-menu ' ;
    $location  = get_nav_menu_locations();
    if ( isset ( $location [ $location ])) {
        $menu  = get_term ( $location [ $location ], ' nav_menu ' );
        if ( $items  = wp_get_nav_menu_items ( $menu -> name )) {

            foreach ( $items  as  $item ) {
                if ( in_array ( $css_class , $item -> classes )) {
                    register_sidebar ( array (
                        ' id '    =>  ' mega-menu-widget-area- '  .  $item -> ID ,
                        ' name '  =>  $item -> title  .  ' Mega Menu' ,
                    ));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'widgets_init' , 'wpmm_init' );
```

но по выходу выпадает ошибка по :  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in

не понимаю как исправить

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50475357/illegal-offset-type-in-isset-or-empty-warning-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в синтаксисе имени и id

```
'name'          => sprintf(__($m_title . 'Мега-меню')),
'id'            => "mega-menu-widget-area-$m_id",
```